# Seeding the random number generator

Tags: c++, c, random

I don't recall seeing any program call `srand` with anything but `srand(time(NULL))`. Under what circumstances would one call `srand` with some other value?

Comment: If you want repeatable results, you would use a constant seed.

Comment: Or if you want different seeds for runs of the program that happen to occur at nearly the same time (in that case you'd probably also use a better RNG). Anyway, I've seen programs that mix in the PID or something into the seed.

Comment: Use the `<random>` header, `rand` shouldn't be used anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `rand()` doesn't return random numbers. It's a *pseudo* random generator instead. That's why you get the same sequence of numbers when you call `srand()` with the same argument. Calling `srand()`with the current time is the actually only random item. The numbers you get from `rand()` are just scrambled.

You will call `srand()` with a predictable or constant value when you want to `replay` a sequence, debug a functionality with the same sequence again and again.