# I am trying to make a random number generator between 5 and 8 in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I need this code to generate a number between 5 and 8 and then assign it to a variable. However when i make it give me only one number instead of multiple, it only gives me the same number. While when i have it set to give e multiple it gives me random numbers.

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(5, 8);

    for (int n=0; n<1; ++n)
        std::cout << dis(gen) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to set the seed of the `random_device` to a different value each time. `random_device` is allowed to be a PNRG. You can check it by calling it many times, e.g by putting `rd()` in the `cout` loop.

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22890738/seeding-the-random-number-generator/22891670#22891670

Comment: We have srand in it, it still doesn't work.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23838367/2567683)

Comment: FWIW in my implementation, I get different numbers each time.

Comment: How can i set the seed of random_device then?

Comment: @harper `rand` and `srand` are (thankfully) entirely separate from the C++11 RNGs.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you get the same sequence when looping more than once or not? And what compiler/platform are you using?

Comment: http://codepad.org/ZSo2fVxU   I managed to find this and it works except i need a way for it only to give me one.

Comment: @delnan Despite the implementation in C++11 is completely different the statement about pseudo random numbers and seeding applies entirely.

Comment: @user3317455 Give you only one what? Random number? Call the distribution once, and it'll give you a single random number. And what compiler/version/platform etc. are you using?

Answer (score 6):

**1 -** You have "only one number" :

Because your for-loop does only one iteration.

```
for (int n=0; n<1; ++n)
                ^
               Here
```

**2 -** If you always see the same pseudo random sequence, this is because the seed is itself pseudo random: for a `std::random_device`, this is [implementation specific](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) :

> Note that std::random_device may be implemented in terms of a
>   pseudo-random number engine if a non-deterministic source (e.g. a
>   hardware device) is not available to the implementation.

Note that your example on ideone is not pseudo random and works fine: http://ideone.com/lysKrt

Alternatively to `rd`, you can use the system time as a seed :

```
    #include <chrono>
    // ...

    unsigned seed = std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    std::mt19937 gen(seed);
```

Comment: -1. You have to explain why the seed "won't change" (see my first comment.) OP is setting the seed using `random_device`.

Comment: Sure: edited with the explanation (rd might be pseudo random)

Answer (score 0):

It is because the executable always starts from the same seed. If you want different numbers in each run then you need to seed the generator. Say, with the current time.

Comment: -1. You should explain how it can be that the same seed is being used. There is an attempt to seed the generator each time.